# Provide 220v to motorhub 36v 500w using a voltage regulator

Tags: electric-bike

The idea is to solar power a bike without battery using a grid-tie inverter that provides 220v and then regulate voltage to link directly with motorhub.

Possible ? Risky? Dumb?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: grid-tie inverter -- so you plan to carry around the electricity grid that the grid-tie inverter needs in order to work?

Comment: Do you have an indoor velodrome at your house?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its better suited on the electrical engineering site.  It's not a bicycle question.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a way to use 220v, or just any way to use solar for powering a bike? Because that seems to have been done already. (But judging by the number of solar bikes I see, not successfully)

Answer (score 3):

You want to power a bike only from a panel?  With no storage in between?

Consider that a watt is a watt.  You will need 500 W of solar input in order to provide 500 W of output to your motor, and that's before any conversion losses.

As you boost the 12V output from the panel to 220V for the inverter to make AC, then there will be loss.

Then you have 220V AC on your bike - bikes aren't intended to be ridden while connected to a wall AC power outlet. They are intended to be stationary while charging.  So you're going to have to convert 220V AC to the 36V DC battery voltage your system expects.   This means more losses.

Estimate 20% loss compounding at every conversion and two conversions so far, and you're now needing **720W of solar panel** at a minimum.

---

Assume you can find high efficiency solar panels, you will need 3.5 square metres of surface area because

> modern solar panels are around 20% efficient, so that works out to approximately 200 watts per square meter, or 20 watts per square foot.

Your 720W requirement demands 3.5 square metres which is roughly the upper surface area of a double bed.

Also consider that to get peak efficiency, your panel has to be at right-angles to the sun, and the sun has to be up and clearly visible.    Any cloud, shadow, rain, or dirt will drop the efficiency of your panel and require more.

---

**Weights**

> A standard 60 cell 1.7m2 solar panel weights around 18kg, while a 72 cell 2.3m2 module weighs around 23.5kg

To get 4 square metres that's going to be around 40 kilograms in solar panels, plus whatever structure you need to support them.   At the minimum you're adding 60 kilograms and probably more like 80-100 kilograms of weight on your bike by the time all the wiring and motor are installed.

Panels are also fragile.  They don't like being dropped or hit, so having your bike fall over once could render all the panels useless.

---

**Legalities** - fitting a 4m<sup>2</sup> panel would require a 2x2 metre "roof" or a 4x1 metre long strip.  Both are large and unweildy and would be a sail if the wind or a side-draught caught it.  Also consider your liability by choosing to use the roadway with such dimensions on your bike.

---

Apologies if this all sounds dreadfully negative on your idea.

What you can do instead is use a couple of normal ebike batteries, each adding perhaps 3-5 kilograms and in a nice aerodynamic package.   Fit your solar panels stationary to your home and use them to charge your batteries when you're not riding.  Use a solar controller that has a dump function, and wire that to a hot water cylinder or similar to not waste the power you generate.

Comment: If you were running a rickshaw or rosalie/surrey (slow, heavy and with a roof anyway, also tends to wait around for customers) with an electric motor, a top-up panel on top might extend the range in a sunny country.  That's about the limit of usefulness

Comment: @ChrisH that's an excellent idea, but a top-up panel implies there is something to top-up, likely the battery that OP specifically excludes.   I think this setup would work better with a battery which starts fully charged from the wall, and then the panel is used to trickle charge/maintain the battery.  But its not feasable to power the bike from the panel only.

Comment: that's what I was thinking of - without a battery it's just not going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Overall I think it is an interesting problem that really not suited to be solved on this site as it is really an electronics problem. In theory it could be done. In practice I doubt there is any off the shelf electronics that will work reliably.

Biggest problem would be the Grid tied inverter probably won't output any power.  Outputting power when there is no grid connection is dangerous and illegal in most jurisdictions. An electrician, linesman etc might isolate the house and check the circuit is not live, the sun comes out and they get electrocuted.   Further the 220V means the entire project falls under low voltage regulations (Most jurisdictions this means some for of electrical practicing license and strict regulations). Sticking to typical solar panel, battery and motor voltages for this kind of application means you fall under Extra Low Voltage regulations which often allow anyone to work on.

Second problem is reliability of sunshine and what happens when the panel is producing less than 100%. Would changes in panel output make the system unusable? With the right control system it could be done.

If you ignore the inverter problem you could and bypass the 220V, and even bypass any controllers and output the solar panel power direct to the motor.  Solar panels are a current source - size the panel so its current matchs that of the motor and you are nearly done. All that is left is to add a controller to limit power when less then maximum is not needed.

Easiest solution to this problem is to add a battery and solve two very common and well understood problems separately - charging a battery from solar and driving a bicycle motor from battery.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, as bike battery systems move while discharging, they won't be designed to charge and run at the same time. It might work perfectly, it might cause something to fail, or the battery management system might refuse to do both. Further, the BMS is designed to charge off a power supply with a large output current and guaranteed voltage. That's not going to work too well when your solar voltage sags as you load it. You'd need a well-designed custom power circuit even with a battery - but the battery is a very good idea, and could be smaller with solar

Comment: @Chris - battery charging and use is a common setup - exactly what any off grid solar installation does (RV, houses etc). Nothing particularly special about it.  For a bicycle, yes current controllers and battery packs are not designed around it, but I can't see anything special required beyond the physical hookups and an appropriate voltage solar controller.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to design something - but it would be a case of designing it properly down to the level of individual components, as has been done in the systems you discuss. RV systems are a bit of a red herring as they're generally lead-acid, which is much more forgiving (Li batteries are starting to be used, with internal circuits designed to make them mimic lead acid)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't doable by wiring together off-the-shelf products.

To even start to define the parameters of the necessary design would require a decent working knowledge of variable frequency motor drives (designing your own inverter).

Also consider the size of solar panels you'd need to get a decent level of assistance. That's probably the reason this hasn't been done commercially. The peak power rating isn't what's applicable here - you never get that in practice even if you can optimise the siting and angle of the panel, which you can't when you're moving. So if you imagine covering the top of a quadricycle or a cycle rickshaw with solar panels, you still wouldn't get the 250W that's typical for motor assistance. The power would drop every time you went into shadow, and surge again as you came out into full sun.

Answer (score 0):

This is a stupid idea for many reasons.

Bicycles need at least 100 watts to go at any reasonable speed, but on hills you will crash due to lack of speed if you don't have 500 watts.

100 watts of panels is half a square meter, 500 watts is two and half square meters. That's given perfect orientation of the panels and no clouds.

Can you imagine what even a half of square meters of panels does to your air resistance? Half a square meter is what the `Cd*A` coefficient of a typical bike is. I'd say solar panels have a very poor `Cd` of about 1.0 and the `A` is between 0.5 and 2.5 square meters, so you'd be at the very least doubling, at the worst sextupling your air resistance.

That's assuming perfect orientation and no clouds. How on Earth are you ensuring perfect orientation as you ride in different directions? I guess you could add some kind of electric tracking device.

Also, the half a square meter or "wings" makes the bike extremely unstable in wind. I wouldn't ride such a bike.

If you add a battery, the 100 watts sounds to make more sense than the 500 watts since you can get the 500 watts for hills from the battery and provide on the average only 100 watts. It would "only" double your air resistance. Still it wouldn't work in cloudy weather at all since clouds capture maybe 75% of the energy, so the 500 watts of panels would actually be the correct choice for cloudy weather.

If you use solar panels, it would be much better to float-charge a LiFePO<sub>4</sub> battery with DC and use that directly to power the motor, not by adding an inverter to 220 volts and then regulating that to 36 volts. That adds two inefficient and unnecessary power conversion stages. Besides, a grid-tie inverter is not the correct kind of inverter, since a grid-tie inverter needs the grid to work. Presumably you aren't carrying the electricity grid around, are you?

Still, even with 100 watts of panels and a battery, that's an incredibly stupid idea. Remember that air resistance is by far the largest resistance force on a bike. If it takes 100 watts to overcome a `CdA` of 0.5, and if adding those 100 watts of panels are increasing the `CdA` by 0.5, you see this is basically impossible ... unless you reduce your speed so much that your solar-powered bike would be much slower than the bike that's going to overtake you, the bike that only uses muscle power.

I have a better idea. Start farming food! This food will capture solar energy in the form of chemical energy. Once you eat that food, you basically have a solar powered bike. I have quite a few of those solar powered bikes...

Comment: A source for the "at least 100 watts" would be nice

Comment: I'd also like to know why having less than 500W would make you crash on a hill?  Most cyclists don't climb at 500W and they dont seem to crash.

Comment: Generally, one would mount solar panels facing towards the sky, not forwards/backwards. Air resistance shouldn’t be as disastrous as you’re imagining.

Comment: 500W or you fall over? Are you serious? Being able to sustain 500W for more than a few minutes would be an exceptional rider, for 5+ minutes would be podium-tier professional riders. Think about the things you post before you hit submit.